# Traffic Forward to Specific gateway (Elastix - CentOS)

Tags: centos, elastix

I need the information regarding multiple interface card.

My Scenario is:

```
Eth0: 172.X.X.X / X.X.X.252 GW 172.X.X.105
Eth1: 192.168.X.X / X.X.X.0 GW 192.168.1.1
```

My Requirement is that:

1. Eth0 traffic out/in gateway 172.X.X.105
2. Eth1 traffic in/out gateway 192.168.1.1

Mean that traffic generate from eth0 forward to its own gate way, same as eth1.

I am using the elastix server (centos) with two sip account, one on eth0 and other eth1. Port number 5060.

I am confused how to do this.

Comment: you need to forward traffic from eth0 to eth1?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up policy based routing, it is not super complicated, but it would be a good idea to read up a bit on iproute2 and how to make proper use of it.

http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Basically, you're going to want to add a specific routing table for each interface, then make sure that packets that arrive to the IP on that interface are then routed back out through that interface. I'm not going to retype out the lartc page because there is a lot of other information there which you should look through.